# How to parse rss new feeds, using php and store in database

Tags: php, parsing, rss

I want to parse information in:

http://feeds.informationweek.com/infoweek/news
http://feeds.news.com.au/public/rss/2.0/fs_breaking_news_13.xml
http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss

using php.

And save the info in my database as: Headline, time, Description, Category

Also category, is show when i click on the link, it shows me the category of article (say world, travel, sports etc)

Plz help me with this issue.

I have never done parsing before.

Zeeshan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not know PHP + MySQL, please read about it first. As for the parsing you got plenty of options:

- [MagPieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/)
- [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/)
- [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for the parsing. From there, it should be pretty straight forward to loop over the items and insert the values into your database.

Comment: Don't use XML parsing libs to parse RSS feeds. They are more irregular than you think. Use a RSS parser. It is much easier.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I'm interested in knowing why an XML parser wouldn't work.

Comment: How do I find out the structure of my rss feed? I mean, when I open the link in my browser, it shows me a simple html page, rather then a structure with tags, which I need to fetch

Comment: @Zeeshan The first and third feeds you've provided only look pretty in your browser because they have an associated XSLT stylesheet. Try "View Source"

Comment: Thank Phil. Can you also tell me about the category. How should I figure out the category of the article.

Comment: @Zeeshan You'll have to give an example. Not sure what you mean

Comment: @Phil, my links http://feeds.informationweek.com/infoweek/news has news articles, and every article falls in a particular category, which i see when i click on the article to view full article. Can you tell me how can I fetch this category of each article to store in my database?